# Received only part of streamed MP4

Tags: python, sockets, video-streaming

I need to live stream video through the internet over sockets in python. I'm using ngrok to expose the internal server. Since separate frames are too slow I tried sending an mp4 file (simplified code):

```
# server (sender)
import socket

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('vid.mp4', 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
    server_soc = socket.socket()
    server_soc.bind(('localhost', 1234))
    server_soc.listen()
    client_soc, _ = server_soc.accept()
    client_soc.send(str(len(data)).rjust(16, '0').encode())
    client_soc.sendall(data)


# client (receiver)
import socket

if __name__ == '__main__':
    soc = socket.socket()
    soc.connect(('6.tcp.eu.ngrok.io', 19717))
    data_len = int(soc.recv(16).decode())
    with open('new.mp4', 'wb') as f:
        read = 0
        while read < data_len:
            f.write(soc.recv(4096))
            read += 4096
```

The problem was that on the internet, the received file was that over the half the size of the sent file.

Comment: I've reduced your question to focus on the code you actually show and which does not work as you've intended,  not on some more general problem where you show nothing about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    while read < data_len:
        f.write(soc.recv(4096))
        read += 4096
```

You blindly assume that `recv` will return 4096 bytes. But, the given number is only the maximum number of bytes `recv` is asked to return, it may return less. So you need to actually check what you got, i.e. something like this

```
    while read < data_len:
         data = soc.recv(4096)
         if not data:
              break # peer has closed
         read += len(data)
         f.write(data)
```